# Reading a CSV File in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to read a form-uploaded .csv file. I am taking my answers in part from several answers: [In Ruby, how to read data column wise from a CSV file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14598302/in-ruby-how-to-read-data-column-wise-from-a-csv-file), [how to read a User uploaded file, without saving it to the database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521053/how-to-read-a-user-uploaded-file-without-saving-it-to-the-database), and [Rails - Can't import data from CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36764566/rails-cant-import-data-from-csv-file). But so far nothing has worked.

Here is my code:

```
def upload_file
  file = Tempfile.new(params[:search_file])
  csv_text = File.read(file)
  csv = CSV.parse(csv_text, :headers => true)
  csv.each do |row|
    puts row
  end
  render json: {success: true}
end
```

I am sure that the file is not nil. It contains 4 columns and 2 rows of simple text. However, my `file` value above comes out as an empty array, and the `csv_text` value is an empty string. I am very sure the file contains values.

I have also tried `params[:search_field].read` and that throws an error every time, saying "undefined method 'read'".

How can I simply read these values from the user uploaded file? I am on rails 5.1.6 and ruby 2.3.

Edit:
I have tried some of the solutions below. However, the problem is that it doesn't write the *contents* of the file, when I call `file.write`--it simply writes the name of the file (like, myFileNameHere.csv) as a string to the temp file. The "ok testing now" never prints to terminal in the below code. Here is my code now:

```
file = Tempfile.new(['hello', '.csv'])
file.write(params[:search_file])
file.rewind
csv_text = file.read
csv = CSV.parse(csv_text, :headers => true)
csv.each do |row|
  puts "ok testing row"
  puts row
end
file.close
file.unlink    # deletes the temp file
```

Comment: I'm betting your *undefined method 'read'* error message says more than what you wrote here. Please indicate the *entire* error message, not just a portion of it. I suspect it says something about 'read' not being defined for a `nil` object or something like that. Check the value of `params[:search_file]`. It's probably `nil` or a file that doesn't exist.

Comment: What is `params[:search_field]`?

Comment: Hi @joey, could you show me the input field in the form?

Answer (score 0):

You are reading from a empty tempfile. When you put params[:search_file], this value will become part of the new Tempfile filename (like this "/tmp/#{params[:search_file]}.24722.0").

So when you do File.read(file) it will try to read a tempfile that has params[:search_file] value in the it's filename but has no other value from the form inside it.

You should either skip the Tempfile part and load the params[:search_file] with File.read(params[:search_file]) or fill the new Tempfile object with params[:search_file] content. (I would recommend the first).

Answer (score 0):

`Tempfile.new('something')` always returns an empty temporary file with 'something' in its basename.

First you create the tempfile (with the filename you want), then you can write the content from `params[:search_file]`, rewind and read it.

Source : [Class: Tempfile (Ruby 1.9.3)](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/tempfile/rdoc/Tempfile.html#class-Tempfile-label-Synopsis)

Comment: I have tried this, but the problem is writing the content via params[:search_file] simply writes it as a string to the file. I edited my question above with new code.